# drupal 7 overlay is not rendering in my site

Tags: drupal-7

I am using drupal 7 for my site.

All of a sudden **/admin/content?render=overlay** showing no data received. :-(

And in console itshowing that defaultVIew is not defined in overlay-parent.js

Comment: If you don't need overlay, you can disabled in admin/modules

Comment: Thanks mjimcua

I disabled overlay module and realized that admin/content is not rendering data. whatever the url followed by admin/ is not rendering the data :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is occurred because in php.ini max_execution_time is set to low and memory_limit value also set to low.